# Google Pubsub Push to AppEngine 502 and 504 Errors

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I am basing this task on the documentation provided here by Google:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages

I ended up coming with this code for my main that takes out the globally stored variable for messages, and instead writes each one out to a flat file.

```
# [START push]
@app.route('/pubsub/push', methods=['POST'])
def pubsub_push():
    if (request.args.get('token', '') != current_app.config['PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']):
        return 'Invalid request', 400
    # Decode the data
    envelope = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    # Current time in UTC
    current_date = datetime.utcnow()

    payload = json.loads(base64.b64decode(envelope['message']['data']))
    # Normalize and flatten the data
    if "events" in payload and payload['events']:
        payload['events'] = payload['events'][0]['data']
    payload = parse_dict(init=payload, sep='_')
    # Now jsonify all remaining lists and dicts
    for key in payload.keys():
        value = payload[key]
        if isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, dict):
            if value:
                value = json.dumps(value)
            else:
                value = None
            payload[key] = value

    # Custom id with the message id and date string
    id = "{}.{}".format(
        payload['timestamp_unixtime_ms'],
        payload['message_id']
    )

    filename_hourly = 'landing_path/{date}/{hour}/{id}.json'.format(
        date=current_date.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
        hour=current_date.strftime("%H"),
        id=id
    )

    blob = bucket.get_blob(filename_hourly)
    if blob:  # We already have this file, skip this message
        print('Already have {} stored.'.format(filename_hourly))
        return 'OK', 200

    blob_hourly = Blob(bucket=bucket, name=filename_hourly)
    blob_hourly.upload_from_string(json.dumps(payload, indent=2, sort_keys=True))

    # Returning any 2xx status indicates successful receipt of the message.
    return 'OK', 200


# [END push]
```

This works perfectly, but I am getting a ton of 502 and 504 errors. It's displayed here in my stackdriver dashboard I created.

[image: Backlog is filling and the errors are high]

My guess is it's taking too long to upload the files, but I am unsure of what to do otherwise. Any suggestions? The resources on the appengine boxes are quite low, and my API limits are not even close.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seemed to have been addressed on the Google Cloud Platform issue tracker [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/109797180). As explained on that link, usually, 5xx responses are from nginx commonly caused when application is too busy to respond. The nginx webserver sits in front of App Engine application on Google App Engine Instance.

However, further review suggests to avoid the use gevent async workers  with the Google Cloud Client Library as they cause requests to hang, but instead use more [gunicorn workers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#recommended_gunicorn_configuration).